# Getting cardinality of multiple fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I get count of all unique combinations of values of 2 fields that are present in documents of my database, i.e. achieve the same functionality as the "cardinality" aggregation provides, but for more than 1 field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better solution is to use nested aggregations and then count the resulting buckets.

```
"aggs": {
    "Group1": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "Field1",
            "size": 0
        },
        "aggs": {
            "Group2": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "Field2",
                    "size": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please specify how to get the no of buckets without just checking the length of the array.

Comment: @pravindot17, just count the number of groups that this query returns.

Comment: @user626528
Does it ensure cardinality aggregation? Can I make the filters more complex, adding "and"/"or" conditions?

Comment: This solution is very expensive for the server. Beware to use it on big amounts of data.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a script to achieve this. Assuming the character '#' is not present in any value of both the fields (you can use anything else to act as a separator), the query you're looking for is as under. Mind you, scripting will come with a performance hit.

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "multi_field_cardinality" : {
            "cardinality" : {
                "script": "doc['<field1>'].value + '#' + doc['<field2'].value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_script_2).